# Sending API request via Postman?

Tags: javascript, post

I am applying for a job using an API which I've never done before. I have no idea what I'm doing and Postman is giving me an error saying: ReferenceError: Request is not defined.
Note: for now I'm using the test script until I'm ready to actually send it.

Here's my code:

```
const url = 'https://url.org';

let info = {
  applicant: 'John Doe',
    "users":[
     {
        "first_name":"John",
        "last_name": "Doe",

        "company_name": "Company",

        "company_full_address": "Address Here", 

       "website": "Website",

       "phone": "5555555555"
    } 
  ]
}

let success = {
  "success" : "True",
  "message" : "Thank you {John Doe} for your application"
}

var request = new Request(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: info,
    headers:{ 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
});

fetch(request)
.then(function() {

let formatData = info.users;
var array = [];
  
    for (var i = 0; i < formatData.length; i++){
      array.push([i,formatData[i]])
      console.log(array);
    }

})

.then(function() {
 console.log(success);
})
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman is an app that emulate what your code is doing.Globally , it's a REST API App emulator.
what you have to do is,copy the content of info. Put it in body tab in postman and set it as JSON, put the content of "const url" in postman url field. And press SEND button.

More informations here : https://learning.postman.com/docs/publishing-your-api/documenting-your-api/